# Creating a Start Menu link with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a batch file that will move my java program into a folder, create a desktop shortcut and then create a shortcut in the start menu.  I've got all of that working thus far except the start menu shortcut.  Here's what I have for the start menu shortcut...

```
@Echo off
set Location="Start Menu"

set DisplayName="Product Code Distributor"
set filename="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ProductCodeDistributor\PCDistrib.jar"

set icon="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ProductCodeDistributor\Icon.ico, 0"

set WorkingDir="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ProductCodeDistributor"

set Arguments=""

(echo Dim DisplayName,Location,Path,shell,link
echo Set shell = CreateObject^("WScript.shell"^)
echo path = shell.SpecialFolders^(%Location%^)
echo Set link = shell.CreateShortcut^(path ^& "\" ^& %DisplayName% ^& ".lnk"^)

echo link.Description = %DisplayName%
echo link.TargetPath = %filename%
echo link.Arguments = %arguments%

echo link.WindowStyle = 7
echo link.IconLocation = %icon%

echo link.WorkingDirectory = %WorkingDir%
echo link.Save

)> "%temp%\makelink.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%temp%\makelink.vbs"
del "%temp%\makelink.vbs" 2>NUL
```

I think it might just be as simple as a different "Location" variable, but I have next to no dos / batch file experience.

Comment: Location should be StartMenu with no space.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location of the Start Menu like this:

```
set startMenuLocation=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

This of course assumes it is a Windows 7 system. To make your batch file dynamics, you can use the `ver` command and tailor startMenuLocation depending on its output.

Comment: but how do you make a Start Menu pin with the location alone ?

Answer (score 1):

> Location should be StartMenu with no space